# Handle String coming of Ajax

Tags: ajax, dictionary, key, handle, key-value

good night.

Personally, I have a function in Ajax that sends to a Servlet a String in the same output template below.

```
{"Disease":["name","class"],"Ingredient":["name"]}
```

What I would like to know is if you can get this output and handles it in such a way that I can turn the values outside the **square brackets []** in **Key** *(such as Disease, for example)* and the **values inside the brackets []** *(such as ["name", "class"], for example)* in Values of my **Map** .

Where each "Key" would have only their respective property Values. My idea is to build a Map follows below.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> mapAjax = new LinkedHashMap<String, Set<String>>();
```

To the output that I mentioned as an example, I would like to have the following final result.

```
Map<Disease, ["name","class"]>;
Map<Ingredient, ["name"]>;
```

Could someone give me a hint how to manipulate this String I have as output?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look up a JSON deserializer in whatever language you're writing in (looks like Java, but it could be C#).

Comment: I am using Java. The result of the String that I posted is the Json result I get from a function in Ajax. Know any tutorial that shows practical examples of a JSON deserializer? Thank you.